# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED I can not connect my Ubuntu Server

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, firewall, django, ubuntu-18.04

I have Ubuntu server that I am serving Django project. But I can not browse anything. I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error on all browsers.

Server host, OS, and applications:

- Digital Ocean Ubuntu 18.04 (LTS) x64
- nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
- ufw 0.36

Here is my nginx and ufw configs:

```
$ systemctl status nginx

● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-03-25 11:31:11 UTC; 5h 21min ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)  Main PID: 18638 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1152)    CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─18638 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_pr
           └─18643 nginx: worker process

$ sudo ufw status

Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
21/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
25/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
21/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
25/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

nginx site-enabled config file

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 188.166.117.124;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ahubelkis/personal_web_site/personal_web_site;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /home/ahubelkis/personal_web_site/personal_web_site;
    }

    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ahubelkis/personal_web_site/personal_web_site/personal_web_site.sock;
    }
}
```

---

```
$ sudo systemctl restart nginx

nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

What is the problem of my configs.

Answer (score 0):

A port scan of your IP (gleaned from your nginx config) states that the only port open on that host is 22.

Perhaps try temporarily disabling UFW with `sudo ufw disable` and then see if you can connect?

Comment: I've tried but nothing changed. Is it possible to problem is related about https (SSL) settings?

Comment: If you disabled the firewall and still nothing changed, then it's not simply https settings - which, by the way, based on what you showed above, you aren't using.

I would double-check your IP address and everything else before proceeding. Something is off.